# How do I make a VM discover physical hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, ssd, virtual-machine

I have an SSD where I store all of my virtual disks on.

I also have an 8TB drive I want to use to store all of the VM data. Example: Im running pfsense with web caching. Pfsense is on a virtual disk on the ssd, but I want the web cache to be stored in a directory on my 8TB drive. Well when I go to change the directory to my 8TB drive\pfsense\ it doesnt list it as an option.

Using virtual box latest version. pfsense latest version.

Comment: You have to share the directory with the Virtual Machine, this means installing the Vbox extensions within the guest OS, you cannot share the entire SSD unless you share the root directory (THIS IS NOT ADVISED).

Comment: Any secure way to do what I want to do?

Comment: I just told you how to do it, share a directory with the guest OS, the root of the 8TB disk doesn't need to be shared in order to store the VM on it

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is VirtualBox's raw disk functionality: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html

Or, if you're trying to pass through a disk controller on a PCIe card, then you're looking for PCIe passthrough.